# Graficar una función en R

Tags: r, algoritmos, rstudio

Estoy tratando de graficar esta funcion que calcula numeros de Fibonacci:

```
    f <- function(x)
     {
         m<-0
         n<-1
         o<-0
         for(i in 1:x){
             o<-m+n
             m<-n
             n<-o
         }
      }
```

En un principio use `print(o)` para mostrar los números calculados y funciono bien, ahora trato de hacer la grafica que corresponde a o.

Probe con esto:

```
g <- Vectorize(f, 'x')
plot(1:10, g(1:10), type = "l")
```

Y me dio este error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: Bienvenido @PacorrOz a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema está que la función `f` no retorna nada, porque hay que añadirle `return(n)`.

Adicionalmente hay que tener presente que la secuencia Fibonacci empieza en `1` incluso si la función fuera recursiva.

En este caso la variable `n` cumple con lo expuesto porque se asigna `1` al inicio, antes de entrar al bucle `for`.

No obstante lo anterior, si se tiene `f(1)` el bucle `for` no debería ser ejecutado, por tanto el rango para la variable `i` es `x-1` o dicho de otra manera `i in 1:(x-1)` o también `i in 2:x`

El código por lo expuesto quedaría así

```
f <- function(x){
    m<-0   # "m" se emplea para actualizar "o" en el bucle "for", por tanto sí
           # corresponde que sea definida en esta instancia.

    n<-1   # Se garantiza que la serie fibonacci empiece en "1" para todo "x<=1"

    # o<-0 # Cuando se tiene f(1), no es necesario definir "o" 
           # porque sólo se emplea para actualizar "n" a partir del segundo
           # número de Fibonacci

    if(x>1){  # sólo se ejecuta si se requiere los números siguientes
              # de la serie Fibonacci
        for(i in 2:x){
            o<-m+n
            m<-n
            n<-o
            # print(paste0(i,": ", o," ", m, " ",n)) # sólo para efectos de control
        }
    }

    return(n) # se puede reemplazar también por: n
}

g <- Vectorize(f, 'x')
plot(1:10, g(1:10), type = "l")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicionalmente si quisieras los valores en el rango que se definió `1:10`

```
for (i in 1:10) print(paste0(i,": ",f(i)))

[1] "1: 1"
[1] "2: 1"
[1] "3: 2"
[1] "4: 3"
[1] "5: 5"
[1] "6: 8"
[1] "7: 13"
[1] "8: 21"
[1] "9: 34"
[1] "10: 55"
```